Resizing Qemu image and extending partitions
I have a qemu image which I use for an XBOX emulator. The disk contains several partitions and the partition where stuff gets installed on, is full. I made the initial image too small.
I already found out that I can resize the qemu image with "qemu-img resize". I have already done this.
However, the partitions inside the disk image don't make use of this newly created space, I think.
Is there a way for me to extend the partitions inside the disk image?
I am on WIndows 11.
Thanks for any suggestions!
